# Swift - Cast URLRessourceValue to String in order to modify .tagNames

Tags: swift, url

I would like to change part of the information retrieved via ".resourceValues(forKeys: [.tagNamesKey]" but I don't find the right way to cast the result (URL resourceValue) to string(via decode). Could someone help me? Thanks.

```
do
{
     let srcURL : URL = nsurl2 as URL
     let pastilleSousRp = try srcURL.resourceValues(forKeys: [.tagNamesKey])
     let test = String(decoding: pastilleSousRp.tagNames, as: UTF8)
      if ((pastilleSousRp.tagNames?.contains("Specific tagname")) != nil)
      {...}
}catch{continue}
```

The error is : "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"(for test).

Comment: `pastilleSousRp.tagNames` that's a `[String]?`, so why `String(decoding: pastilleSousRp.tagNames, as: UTF8)`? What do you expect? What about `let tagsNames = pastilleSousRp.tagNames ?? []; if tagNames.contains("Specific tagname") { ... }`?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I used "(decoding..." because it was suggested by Xcode. I expected "[String]" for answer, so your suggestion is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

`pastilleSousRp.tagNames` is a `[String]?`

So you just want:

```
if let tagNames = pastilleSousRp.tagNames, tagNames.contains("Text") {
    //Do your thing 
}
```

Or, you can also do:

```
let tagNames = pastilleSousRp.tagNames ?? []
if tagNames.contains("Text") {
    //Do your thing 
}
```

In a shorter way:

```
if (pastilleSousRp.tagNames ?? []).contains("Text") {
    //Do your thing 
}
```